# Difficulties on emulating AT91SAM9260 embedded Linux on qemu-system-arm virt machine

Tags: linux, arm, kernel, virtual-machine, qemu

I've built a kernel and root file system for the AT91SAM9260 with the following  buildroot menu selections on "Filesystem Settings":

[image]

And the kernel build settings including the at91_dt_defconfig option.

buildroot's output folders contained the following images:

rootfs.cpio  rootfs.ext2  rootfs.tar  zImage

I've tried to boot using qemu with the following commands:

`qemu-system-arm -machine virt -kernel zImage -initrd rootfs.cpio -hda rootfs.ext2 -append "console=ttyS0,115200 root=/dev/sda" -serial stdio`

Which resulted in a blank qemu screen.

What am I doing wrong? Is it a qemu operation or buildroot configuration problem?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that a kernel will only boot on a piece of Arm hardware if it is compiled for that hardware. Otherwise it will generally fail, usually by crashing before it is able to output anything useful. This is because (unlike x86 systems), every embedded Arm board and SoC is different to every other one, with different devices, devices and RAM at different addresses, and so on. The QEMU "virt" board is not an AT91SAM9260, and will not run a kernel that is built for that SoC.

You can either:

- build a kernel that is intended to run on the 'virt' board, and run it
- write device models and an SoC model for QEMU for the SoC you're interested in (beware that this is a large amount of work; it's about as much effort as porting the Linux kernel and writing device drivers for the hardware would be; it also requires either having or learning quite a lot about QEMU's internals)